# "Compress item" inside Time Machine backup

Tags: finder, backup, time-machine

Trying to compress (by right-click + "Compress item") an item inside a Time Machine drive's `/Volumes/drive_name/mac_name/Latest` folder will put the resulting `.zip` file on `/Users/user_name/Desktop` on the host computer.

This of course does not happen with other external drives not used as Time Machine backups.

Why does this happen? And **how does it work**, under the hood, the process of detecting that I'm trying to create a new compressed file in a Time Machine drive and of making a copy of the new compressed item to `~/Desktop`?

Answer (score 1):

> Why does this happen?

Because the Time Machine backup is read-only.

This behavior isn't specific to Time Machine; the same thing will happen if you try to compress an item that's in a read-only area of your hard disk (like `/System`), or an item on a read-only disk or network volume.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the user does not have permission to write to the Backup: only the system does.

If you are trying to save space on a backup that is full, then that's not the way to do it, and you should modify your question accordingly.